# Solving the follow a person problem in ROS Melodic

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

I have this project where I need to solve the problem of tracking a person in a room. I am currently working on a skid-steer platform that has a 2D LiDAR and a D435 depth camera.

Let's say I am able to extract a position (x,y) of the person to be tracked with respect to the odometry. I have developed two approaches, for the moment:

- In the first approach, I detect a person and using a PID control I control the distance at which the robot is located and try to keep it always in the center (here I only use the depth camera). This solution works very well in terms of speed and fluidity, however, it is not able to avoid dynamic and static obstacles.
- In the second approach, I tried to use the DWA local planner that comes in move_base by itself, without global map and global planner. This solution allows the robot to dodge obstacles but it is very slow and unreliable, as it gets stuck quickly.

At this point I need help, is there a standard way to follow people in a room? state of the art? I have searched in current papers but it has been hard to find an established solution.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the standard Nav2 navigation stack. By pairing the 'navigate to pose' functionality with code that detects a person to update the goal pose, a follow-me behavior that avoids obstacles is produced.

Documentation can be found here: [Nav2/General Tutorials/Dynamic Object Following](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_dynamic_point_following.html).

> This tutorial shows how to use Nav2 for a different task other than going from point A to point B. In this case, we will use Nav2 to follow a moving object at a distance indefinitely.
>
> This task is useful in cases such as following a person or another robot. Below are some sample videos of applications that could be created using this capability. The “Carry My Luggage” RoboCup @ Home test, in which the CATIE Robotics team performs the test successfully and this real (future) world application:

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. Is this available on ros melodic? (forgot to say that in the title)

Comment: Nav2 is for ROS 2, so not with this approach. However, the same concept can be applied to the navigation stack for ROS 1, which will also provide going to a goal that you can update. Look up 'move_base' and you should get a decent starting place.